# Wordpress search results

Tags: custom-post-types, search, query

I have installed Job Manager and managed to filter the search to only display jobs (i.e. post_type = jobman_job) and it works ok however, when displaying the search results, it only shows the title - it does not pull the short description (the "excerpt") like the normal search does.

Can anyone give me some direction on how to make the search display the job content?

Comment: Did you create a `search.php` template file in your theme? Could you show us your [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used post_type to differentiate the specific Job Manager posts and search those